# How can I output a sentence to JSX while coloring the words that match a given word in a different color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```js
    export default function App() {
      const defaultText = "Your partner for software innovations";
      const colorText = "software";

      const result = defaultText.split(" ").map((txt) => txt);
      return <div className="App">{result}</div>;
    }
```

`defaultText` is my data from the backend.

`colorText` is a word that should be colored.

So I am trying to do the following. I want to map through the `defaultText` and if `txt === colorText`, then display that word in red, so the final result would read "Your partner for software innovations" with the word "software" in red.

I easily can map `defaultText` as you see but I can't understand how to implement that filtering logic.

Comment: `.map((txt) => txt === colorText)`...? Not quite clear what problem you are facing.

Comment: I can't achieve the expected result

Comment: You need to wrap the appropriate text in a `span` and style it

Comment: use regex, `defaultText.replace(new RegExp('(softWare)', 'ig'), '<span class="highlight">$&</span>')`, though be wary of XSS etc, https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-shape-pomvkb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Guys, could you show me the whole code? ... I do not understand where to write and what to do after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the text into parts and then add a class to the text to highlight.

Pseudo code:

```js
const defaultText = "Your partner for software innovations";
const colorText = "software";

const segments = defaultText.split(colorText);

return (
  <div className="App">
    {segments.map((segment, index) => (
      <Fragment key={index}>
        <span>{segment}</span>
        {(index !== segments.length - 1) && (<span>{colorText}</span>)}
      </Fragment>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

And CSS:

```css
span.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

If you want the keyword to match regardless of the letter's case, you can use RegEx when `split`ting.

Comment: This one's pretty cool, but I think you should make it work with multiple matches. At least, that's the impression I was under when reading the problem.

Comment: it a little bit works incorrect,  your [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-browser-ktde9c) returning something like this `Your partner for software innovationssoftWare`

Comment: but anyway thanks for help

Comment: @someone Yes, because your colorText has wrong caps. I thought you knew about it already.

Comment: @caTS I know. That's why I said pseudo code. Updating it for more general use case.

Comment: oh I see, my fault

Comment: Updated for a bit more general use case.

Comment: @someone And if you want it to match regardless of the letter case, you can use RegEx when `split`ting.

Comment: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-nash-ojqshx) is the final working version.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the string, with the same string but with a style="color:(some color);"

```
defaultText.replace("software", "<span style='color:red;'>software</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const defaultText = "Your partner for software innovations";
  const colorText = "software";

  const result = defaultText
    .split(" ")
    .map((txt) =>
      txt === colorText ? (
        <span className="colorText">{colorText} </span>
      ) : (
        <span>{txt} </span>
      )
    );
  return <div className="App">{result}</div>;
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.colorText{
   color red
```

}

Try out with this solution. It worked for me